# Why is qmake ignoring the -spec flag?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qmake

I've got many different VS instances on a build machine, so I'm using the `-spec` flag to tell `qmake` to generate the right kind of project. Unfortunately, Qt seems to be ignoring it and continues to use the wrong compiler:

```
[01:51:01][Step 1/2] Starting: C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\bin\qmake.exe -spec win32-msvc2013 -tp vc Fixer.pro
[01:51:01][Step 1/2] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent4\work\d1b6b25e39f4d573\src\Fixer
[01:51:02][Step 1/2] WARNING: Generator: MSVC.NET: Found more than one version of Visual Studio, but none in your path! Fallback to lowest version (MSVC.NET 2013 (12.0), MSVC.NET 2012 (11.0), MSVC.NET 2010 (10.0))
[01:51:02][Step 1/2] Process exited with code 0
```

Why is this happening? Any way to coerce it to use the VS version I want?

Note: I don't actually have VS2010 installed. I have uninstalled it, yet `qmake` still seems to be able to find it.

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you seem to have several Visual Studio versions installed, namely

> (MSVC.NET 2013 (12.0), MSVC.NET 2012 (11.0), MSVC.NET 2010 (10.0))

as per your error message.

In order to resolve the issue, you either need to set up the `PATH` variable to have the desired Visual Studio in in there first. that means VS2013 in this particular case based on the parameter passed to the `-spec` option of qmake.

This is one solution, but you could also solve this issue by running the corresponding terminal installed by VS2013 in your special case. If you run that properly from the start menu, it will launch the prompt while setting up the necessary environment for you.

Hope this clarifies the confusion.

Comment: Setting the `PATH` explicitly does not help the matter: qmake is still complaining. Here's what I'm using: `set path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin";"c:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\bin\"
qmake.exe -tp vc -spec win32-msvc2012 Fixer.pro`

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: try to set the PATH variable on your desktop with Environment Variables from right click settings. You will also need to make sure to run the visual studio .bat script explicitly in cmd.exe what the visual studio terminal is also running, but it is easier to just run the dedicated terminal from the start menu. Did that work?

Comment: We're talking about build servers here - they serve lots of different builds, and setting `PATH` unilaterally is unrealistic. Furthermore, even if this was a dev machine, it would equally make very little sense to set. The amazing thing is that `qmake.exe` detects also versions of VS which I do *not* have, such as VS2010. Weird, just plain weird.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: I do not follow. You need to have a command prompt to build things, so why don't you use the proper one? Which build server is this? Hudson? Jenkins or something else?

Comment: I'm using TeamCity, and I don't follow either. You said that setting a path disambiguates the generation of the right `.vcxproj`, but this is evidently not the case - even after I set a PATH (I do this in a batch file), the `qmake` invocation *still* complains of finding far too many VS versions.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: have you read that I wrote that also you need to run the relevant vcs bat file from the corresponding installation? I think you skipped that. That is important!

Comment: Indeed I did. Here's a screenshot to illustrate: http://postimg.org/image/lfrv19lqf/

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: Hmm, I see. This is really strange, I must confess. :)

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't